# What are some drawbacks of an API driven design, using jQuery JSON requests in a "Page-less" design under ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc, api, templates

Here's what I'm envisioning. Take a database (this one uses sql server 2008 spatial types/queries extensively). Build data access based on repository pattern. Setup controllers to return JSON data, based on a highly "discoverable" url scheme (/Products/TVs/Sony/27in/All, etc...).

Build a core javascript framework, in a separate file shared amongst the views so that the majority of the js code is cached on the client side.

Use the core framework methods to call those discoverable urls, pulling data via a JSON call, then utilize the MS jQuery templates to render it on the client.

Ensure these calls are cached, server side (ala output caching), as much as possible to avoid calls to the database if possible.

Doing this, I imagine many of the repository calls that used to happen in the controller would now be occurring in the view, using the Core framework - should free up much of the load on the server, moving a bit of the work to the clients.

Having no experience with this design, what drawbacks of this design am I not foreseeing? Any good articles out there about this sort of subject? I found [a bit on ZURBlog](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/zurb/blog/~3/dDnUCu_ba7o/building-pageless-apps-with-rails-and-bac) (rails based though).

Comment: I think this would be awesome on an intranet application, but deceze is right that it won't work well for a publicly facing site.

Comment: Dag nabbit... I guess that's true, but oh how I wish it wasn't. Oh well, I guess I could still kind of build it this way, strap OAuth onto it, and call it an API for selected third party developers to take advantage of. ;)

Comment: If you do want to look at going the javascript heavy route, you should check out these libraries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112899/knockout-js-vs-backbone-js-vs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious drawback is that you're relying 100% on Javascript.

You may be leaving clients without or with limited Javascript capability in the dust.
Your site probably won't do very well in search engines, unless you also serve an HTML version.
There may be accessibility problems.

Pure Javascript sites are certainly possible, but the baseline for the web is still HTML. You may be better off starting with basic HTML pages and progressively enhance them using Javascript and JSON-only data transfer for faster page loads where available.

Comment: Those are definitely valid points. So easy to get into the mindset of pure performance. The SEO one is killer, though almost 90% of my traffic comes from Facebook, I don't want to rule out search engine traffic. I suppose you're right, a hybrid structure is likely best. Are there any ways that Google can index jQuery templated html that's dynamically loaded into an existing html "page"?

Comment: @Chad I don't think any search engine really executes Javascript, so anything that can only be discovered through it basically does not exist for search engines.

Comment: Ya, I just read an article on how to build an ajax page in a way that Google can index it, but it looks convoluted. I'll probably just stick with a hybrid design, or maybe build a view that is shown to crawlers in a pure HTML way, but visitors get the javascript version (in a way that does not violate Google "laws" ;] )